# Cannot install pip on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, python3, pip

I am trying to install PyPI (pip) on my Linux/Ubuntu 18.04 LTS operating system without success.

The Linux distribution came pre-packaged with python 3.6 (as it appears in `/usr/bin`), but pip does not seem to be pre-installed as when I try to install a package from a terminal using `pip install <package-name>`, it replies:

`Command 'pip' not found`

I tried installing pip using the following:

`sudo apt install python3-pip` (source: https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/)

`sudo apt install python3-venv python3-pip` (source: https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers)

But everytime, although something is installed, when I try using pip from the command line, it still doesn't find it.

I did not try the method proposed in https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ using get-pip.py because of the following message which appears on their website (I'm worried that this may cause a problem as I believe my Python install is managed by my operating system since it came pre-installed):

*Warning: Be cautious if you are using a Python install that is managed by your operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.*

Do you know have any idea what the problem could be (or what I'm doing wrong) and/or do you know if there are any other way to install pip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm too green to leave this as a comment, but does `python3 -m pip` do anything for you? (`python3 -m pip install pyyaml` for example?)

Comment: Yep, it works ! Thank you so much. Actually, the `--` in front of `install` or other pip commands is not necessary (`python3 -m pip install pyyaml` works fine for me). Nevertheless, I would be interested to know why this works, and why I can't use "pip" directly in the bash terminal, if anyone happens to have the answer.

Comment: The reason is that this package implements pip as a python module rather than a standalone executable (hence "not found"). I hope that's not begging the question.